# Rails before_update callback able to access original data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My `before_update` method needs to update another object only if there was a change to a particular field. Do we have access to the original data or do I need to load it from the database? For example:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :points, :student_id
  belongs_to :student

  before_update :update_points

  private
  def update_points
    if points != original_log.points
      student.points += points - original_log.points
      student.save
    end
  end
end
```

I need that `original_log` or the original `points`. If I don't have access to the database, I assume it's safe to add this under `def update_points`?

```
original_log = Log.find(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but it looks like ActiveModel will keep track for you and provides a `points_was` method. So the following should work:

```
def update_points
  if points != points_was
    student.points += points - points_was
    student.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but I can't find **any** documentation on this! Is `_was` deprecated in modern version of `ActiveRecord`? I'm trying it out now.

Comment: It was exactly like I'd hoped, there's even a `_changed?` method I can use instead of `points != points_was`. The ***only*** documentation I could find on these dirty methods is at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html. It's "a way to track changes in your object in the same way as Active Record does." So it very briefly describes `_was` and I guess we can assume that works in ActiveRecord objects too. I'm a bit concerned given the lack of documentation about this that it's deprecated or not supported.

Comment: `ActiveModel` is one of the modules included in `ActiveRecord::Base`; Rails 3 split a lot of its functionality into separate submodules. So it's current and supported. Glad to be of help!